# PHP Error handler triggers when using die in outputbuffer context

Tags: php, error-handling, die

im developing my PHP framework and at the moment im stuck with a strange behaviour in my error-dispatching page.

The page itself is beautiful, it catches and lists all error using a custom error-handler registered with "set_error_handler()" and can print the line, file, invoked variables and such. It even triggers multiple errors perfectly (except for fatal or syntax-errors which causes the script to hold) but still the dispatches the fatal or even syntax error in this case and even shows me, even when its a null-pointer in a template where the error is located which is beautiful and works awesome.

This system works "using set_error_handler"! The entire output (rendering html /php templates) is realised using "ob_start" and "ob_get_clean" - outputbuffer context.

Next I check if the error-handler catched any errors (will be written in an array in the error-handler's class) and if there are errors and error-display is enabled (developer mode = on) the error-dispatcher page will be displayed instead of the page's content.

However since I implemented that I have one strange behaviour which I do not want:

Whenever I use die() inside of outputbuffer context ((ob_start() ... ob_get_clean()) ) The registered error-handler method is called with an empty error-list displayed and even error_get_last() is empty, but still he triggers that damn function.

This is very disturbing as you cant use die to hold the script to test the output of certain variables which is disturbing in development and seems to be an unusual behaviour to me.

I think posting my entire code is making the thing a little bit too complicated for you to understand thatswhy I leave a little draft explaining the situation, its basically same as it looks in my classes:

```
//index.php
$errorList = array();
function myErrorHandler($errorType, $errorString, $errorFile, $errorLine, array $errorContext) {
    global $errorList;
    $errorList[] = $errorString;
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

//Here my classses and entire rest of framework is loaded...()

//Initialise output
$output = "";

//This method parses templates, it remotely close works like that...
function includeTemplate($templatePath) {
     global $output;
     ob_start("myErrorHandler");
     include($templatePath);
     $output .= ob_get_clean(); //Attach to output

}

//This method is called at the very end, it flushes the output, wether by displaying error-dispatcher or page content to be shown.
function flush() {
    global $output;

    if(count($errorList) > 0) {
        echo implode("<br />", $errorList);
    } else {
        echo $output;
    }
}

//Template file: registerTemplate.php
<div class="container">
<Some template output here, doesnt matter if an error occured...>
    <?php die($var); ?> //<- Error rised -> Entering "myErrorHandler()" -> but why????
</div>
```

-> This die() above would rise an error because registerTemplate.php was somewhen parsed using includeTemplate("reigsterTemplate"); which is as located within an ob_start() context. It does not matter if an error occured before or not or even if I just place die("!"); without any invoked variable, it will riase an error.

If I put the die() before or after the include_template context, in upper scope it works as usual and the error_handler does not trigger, as it should work.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks alot!

(Important: again this code is not realistic I know its just a draft from how the things look like very barely, dont bother with that giving me hints that this is a bad way to do things. The entire thing is perfectly object oriented and very well structured. I just made this little draft to make you guys understand in what order the methods are called and how my problem comes up because posting my code would waste me and you alot of time as it would be too huge and complex here).

Comment: I've written and contributed to a few frameworks and they all recommend the devs using it not use die or exit. I feel breaking the flow that way is a bad practice outside of small scripts.

Comment: Well I dont think its bad practice if you want to debug something and just need a specific value and want to hold the script to check a value maybe before executing a query or something like that. I dont use it in live state nor I would leave a die() somewhere in the code as stated, I only use it in process of development and/or quick debugging of variables. However I do not agree with the fact that my framework behaves like that upon using die() thatswhy this does not help one bit. Thanks for your concern but this is not my goal.